# zero an accelerometer with opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a KXPS5-3157 Accelerometer, that outputs 0.330 to 2.97 VDC

http://www.futurebots.com/3157.pdf

The zero-G offset is 1.65VDC (VCC/2)

1G of gravity = 1.65VDC + 0.440 = 2.09 volts = ZERO to cancel out gravity

I want to "zero" the output of the accelerometer strictly in hardware. I was thinking of using a Differential Amplifier, and inputting -2.09 and the output of the accelerometer to zero it. Not sure if this will work, my application is as follows:

The sensitivity of the accelerometer is 440mV/G

I want to zero out of the accelerometer on the Z axis to cancel out gravity, so subtract 2.09 volts.

Then I want the output of the accelerometer to swing positive G's Positive voltage, and negative G's negative voltage.

I want the accelerometer to output negative and positive voltage corresponding to the -G and +G's, canceling out the affect of gravity also

The supply voltage is 12volts, for the opamp, the accelerometer uses 3.3V I'm assuming a would need a rail to rail opamp?

Think I solved this playing in multi-sim:

I just cant find the correct voltage divider pair to get exactly 0V

[image: [img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPyig.png[/img]]

Comment: Not sure if this is a follow-on of your Arduino questions, but if so is there any reason you don't just subtract in software? Otherwise you'll need some extra work to handle the bipolar signal.

Comment: @PeterJ I was gonna use a peak and envelope detector in analog, the negative G's are important, I was gonna rectify the output of the positive and negative voltages into an envelope and then use an envelope detector until I understand digital filters haha

Comment: You should be using a pot to set the zero point anyway. Unless you have very precise resistors (.1%) or better,  the errors in the resistor values will be too high for most reasonable requirements. That doesn't even take into account other offset effects.